# I get the TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable, but not really about the error

Tags: python, dictionary, typeerror

My question isn't really about why I get the error, because I already found something of a solution, but this one wont work for me. So I tried this

game

```
import random
import listAdventureGame
p_aT = 'no armor'

armor_type = listsAdventureGame.aT
armor_durability = listsAdventureGame.aD
armor_points = listsAdventureGame.aP

game_data = dict(zip(str(armor_type[p_aT]), str(armor_durability[p_aT])))
print(game_data)
p_aP = armor_points[p_aT]
p_aT = random.choice(list(game_data))
p_aD = game_data[p_aT]

print("Armor type:", p_aT)
print("Armor durability:", p_aD)
print("Armor point(s):", p_aP)
```

listAdventureGame

```
aT = {'no armor': 'nothing',
      'light': ('leather armor', 'normal clothes', 'ranger armor', 'animal skins'),
      'medium': ('chain mail armor', 'fireproof cloak', 'tank armor', 'fighter armor', 'copper armor'),
      'heavy': ('plate armor', 'dragon scale armor', 'rune armor')}

aD = {'no armor': 0,
      'light': (100, 75, 90, 105),
      'medium': (130, 110, 145, 115, 120),
      'heavy': (185, 200, 190)}

aP = {'no armor': 100,
      'light': 5,
      'medium': 3,
      'heavy': 2}
```

but then the output is something like

```
Armor type: n
Armor durability: 0
Armor points: 100
```

and I want `Armor type: nothing` and when I change the `p_aT` it still works, I'm going to make this a function somewhere in the future.

I removed the `str()` in the `zip()`

```
game_data = dict(zip(armor_type[p_aT], armor_durability[p_aT]))
```

I'm really just a beginner and a visual learner, so if you're able to do it by showing the code.

Thx in advance

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Unmitigated Trying to find a solution for the first print function, bc first it didn't print the whole word and now I get the error. It works with the other keys in the dictionaries, but not with the 'no armor' one

Comment: What is the expected output? It's not really clear what you mean by finding a solution because you haven't specified what your code is supposed to do.

Comment: @Unmitigated Armor type: nothing, and when I change the p_aT it should change according to the keys

Comment: Okay, but what exactly is this code supposed to be doing? Explaining that will make it much easier for us to help.

Comment: display the stats of the armor of a player, opponent or party member, so the randomness will be left out

Comment: Compare the values in the 1st item of  aT, aD, aP to the 3 others: there's an obvious difference! Modify it to fit the others. To be clearer: replace `'nothing'` with `('nothing',)` ...

Comment: @Swifty, the output of Armor type is good this time, but the last one changed to Armor points: (100,)

Comment: Yes, sorry; I wrote my comment too fast; only the 1st 2 dictionaries needed to be fixed.

Comment: @Swifty, yes nvm, I guessed it was that problem, but thx for answering

Comment: Your question is not a question. You state that you get an error and that you are not asking about it. Then you show some code saying it is a test to solve something but not what. Then you say you are getting a result but not the expected result. First try to figure out what you really are asking put that in the heading. Then tell us what you want to do. Tell us the expected output. Show us the whole code. Show us the output you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, 'when I change the `p_aT` it still works' (I imagine you mean it works with other armor types): if so, find the difference between 'no armor' and other armor types; it lies in the first 2 dictionaries, where you use tuples except for the 'no armor' key. The fix is then easy to devise:

```
aT = {'no armor': ('nothing',), ...
aD = {'no armor': (0,), ...
```

the `game_data` statement will now return the correct result for 'no armor'.

Answer (score 1):

just replace `game_data = dict(zip(armor_type[p_aT], armor_durability[p_aT]))` the with this line of code. `game_data = dict(zip([armor_type[p_aT]], [armor_durability[p_aT]]))`

maybe the zip function only try to match the first and second item character by character. seems awesome but the code above actually works out.

Comment: Thx, what do the extra brackets do?

Comment: make the inside code, a list.